# stringByAppendingString

Tags: iphone, xcode, tableview

I am using Xcode 4.2 storyboard.
I am stuck in this concatenation. Is this right? Where in the code i've to modify?
actually i want to display a new tableview depending on the variable passed ("row") from previous tableview.
Any help appreciated.

```
self.newrow =row;// row is the variable passed from previous tableview

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://ipaddress/iphone.php?id="];

NSString *urlStr=@"";
urlStr=[urlString stringByAppendingString:newrow];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection release];
[request release];
```

Comment: is `self.newRow` a string??  If not (seems more likely to be an `int`) you should maybe use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://whatever?id=%d",self.newRow]`.

Comment: Also, what error are you getting???

Comment: What problem/error are you hitting?  Have you tried logging your string?  Are you implementing the NSURLConnection call backs?

Comment: You don't need to use stringByAppendingString.

Comment: @HotLicks : thanks :) everything working fine. As you pointed there is no need for stringbyAppendingstring. Actually error was in previous view controller where i didn't convert string into integer.

Comment: newrow =row;
    
    
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://ipaddress.php?id=%d",newrow];

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `self.newRow` is an integer change your code to:

```
NSString *urlStr = [urlString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i", self.newrow];
```

The format converts the integer to a string representation.

Several statements can be combined without loosing clarity:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://ipaddress/iphone.php?id=%i", self.newrow];
```